# Pybrain implement network whose outputs are parameters of a function

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I want to build a neural network in pybrain to fit the following function

```
z(t) = A + B x(t) + C(t) y(t)
```

Here, `(x, y, z)(t)` are my experimental data; `A` and `B` are constants and `C(t)` is a function of time. The requirements for my network are:

- Input layer of 4 neurons: t, x, y and z
- output layer of 3 neurons: A, B and C

The two conceptual problems that prevent me from implementing it are

- To train the network, rather than providing the input and output values, I want to minimize the above function
- As I have some prior knowledge (i.e., A and B are constants), I want to explicitly make that they are not time dependent

If the solution is easier using other tools (pylearn2 or scikit-learn) I could also implement it there.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second problem, `pybrain.structure.FullConnection` has *kwargs* `inSliceFrom` and `inSliceTo` that set the neurons that will be taken.